# Background color and svg gradient at top of it bring svg at fornt

Tags: html, css, svg

i need to get this effect in css.
[image]

it's gradient with red as svg this is it:
[image]

and black background in the css:

```
.body-element {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: left;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64, ....");
}
```

Now the effect is only the back background. How to bring this svg to front of this background ?
I know i can make full img in figma but i have to use background in css.

Comment: You can create Gradient from here.
https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: It's ok but it's not exactly what i wont here i cant get this 0-20% gradient from white to red or i don't know how :/

The problem is that i want gradient with 2 colors and background color on the background of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exact effect you want to achieve yet you'll have to use SVG opacity in the gradient to "show through" your background. Here's your SVG, play with the background color of the first rectangle in the code (mimicking your black background):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400">  
 <defs>  
   <linearGradient id="linGradient1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">  
     <stop offset="0" stop-color="#333333" stop-opacity="0.25" />  
     <stop offset="1" stop-color="darkred" stop-opacity="0.75" />  
   </linearGradient>
   <mask id="gradient-mask1">  
     <rect x="100" y="100" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linGradient1)"  />  
   </mask>
</defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" fill="black" />  
  <rect x="100" y="100" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linGradient1)" />  
</svg>
```

Actually I have left the SVG mask definition as well in the code, search Mozilla SVG specification how to use it and maybe it will also spawn more creativity with SVG simple effects.